# includesvg cannot include svg

Tags: graphics

I am trying a **very** simple example of trying to import a svg image, I am following the manual on http://mirrors.acm.jhu.edu/ctan/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf but this doesn't work at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\includesvg{p.svg}
\end{document}
```

but I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg
```

which shouldn't happen.  I don't want to have to keep converting between SVG and EPS (which I can import) because this complicates the image-making process and clutters my directories.
I'm trying to use `includesvg` the same way I would use `includegraphics`, just like the manual said.  The manual isn't giving working examples, and this error doesn't even show up on google searches.

How can I import an SVG image?

Comment: Do you have tried to use `\includesvg{p}` only, i.e. without `.svg` extension?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, this gives the error `! LaTeX Error: File `./p' not found`

Comment: The introduction of the manual mentions the fact that typesetting should be done with the `--shell-espace` flag and Inkscape must be accessible fromt he terminal (by setting the PATH variable on Windows for example). Are you sure these requirements are satisfied in your case?

Comment: @epR8GaYuh running pdflatex with `--shell-escape` and that inkscape is accessible from the terminal make no difference, the same error is produced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to include an SVG file, with the minimal working example, with the file "p.svg":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{p}
\end{document}
```

but.... the package svg-extract (or inkscape) may or may not be installed on your system, which you can install on Ubuntu with

```
con@e:~/Scripts$ sudo tlmgr install svg-extract
[sudo] password for con: 
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/con/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604
```

ignore the last line, it works without this.

The latex script can be compiled to PDF with this:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape svg_graphic.tex
```

Comment: Can you please include your p.svg in this MWE?