# Include SVG file on frame in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, svg

I have an svg file foo.svg which I would like to present in a presentation using latex beamer.

Please give me a minimal working example that accomplishes that. None of the solutions I have found on this site works, they all produce error messages.

Comment: why can you not save the svg as pdf and include that?

Comment: which solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: this complicates the workflow, in particular if the svg file is repeatedly updated.

Comment: @shuhalo not really, since in the end you need to convert it to pdf to include it in a pdf file then either you arrange your build script to convert it or you run pdftex with shell-scape so it calls a convertor, there isn't a lot of difference (the `svg` package offers an interface to calling a conversion from latex if that's what you prefer.

Comment: You should you try this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362240/includesvg-cannot-include-svg